# Will google index my "getdata.php" file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have links like `/getdata.php?name=somebody&id=123` masked by .htaccess like `/somebody-123`

I catched google (or another bot) in Google Analytics looking at my "getdata.php" file.

Normally it's impossible to get that file (if you don't know that it exists  because it doesn't get mentioned anywhere in a code and it just generates the content based on `$_GET` and if you call it alone, it will create a MySQL error.

Now I am scared, that it gets indexed in google and people start clicking on it.

Do I have to be scared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be indexed by google because it's placed as hyper link in your page and when someone click on it, it get some data and query in DB and come back with data on page. (this data can be indexed by google, because google bot has nothing to do with get or post requests. they just scan what is available in page via any link). if you want google or any bots to not index your particular page, just block those pages in your [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file. you can use * for pages that are passing query parameters. read more in the official robots documentation link i provided above.

Comment: if your pages already have indexed, you can goto your google webmasters (signup for one if you don't have) and there you can remove your every single page from google search

Comment: Thank you both! I know about the robots.txt, I was just not shure, how this will be handled.